# myql performance : extremely slow inserts on a faster box

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

**tldr;** When migrating a stack to its pre-prod environment, i am confronted with a setup script taking 50x the amount of time to execute compared to my dev box. error logs are dead silent !

**dev :**
    osx, mysql 5.7, SSD, plenty of memory

**pre-prod :**
    debian 8.6, mysql 5.6, faster SSD, faster/more memory, faster core.

**the PHP script:**

```
    private function _addCityFile($fn)
    {
        $this->log->info(__METHOD__ . " start.");

        $this->log->debug("Adding city file [$fn]");

        try {
            /** @var \PDO $pdo */
            $pdo = $this->pdo;
            $this->pdo->beginTransaction();
            // InnoDB table
            $sql  = "INSERT INTO City SET country=:co,city=:ci,state=:st,zip=:zip";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

            $handle             = fopen($fn , "r");
            $csv_time           = 0.0;
            $pdo_time           = 0.0;
            $index              = 0;
            $intermediate_count = 100;           // echo every 100 records
            $total_count        = 0;

            if ($handle) {
                fgets($handle);                 // skip first line
                while (true) {
                    $index++;
                    $total_count++;
                    $start_csv_once = microtime(true);
                    $ary            = fgetcsv($handle);
                    $end_csv_once   = microtime(true);
                    $csv_time_once  = $end_csv_once - $start_csv_once;
                    $csv_time       = $csv_time + $csv_time_once;

                    if ($ary) {
                        $country = $ary[0];
                        $state   = $ary[1];
                        $city    = $ary[2];
                        if (!$city || $city === '') continue;
                        $zip = strtoupper($ary[3]);
                        if (!$zip || $zip === '') continue;
                        $stmt->bindValue('co' , $country , \PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->bindValue('ci' , $city , \PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->bindValue('st' , $state , \PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $stmt->bindValue('zip' , $zip , \PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $start_pdo_once = microtime(true);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $end_pdo_once  = microtime(true);
                        $pdo_time_once = $end_pdo_once - $start_pdo_once;
                        $pdo_time += $pdo_time_once;
                        $ct = $csv_time * 1000;
                        $pt = $pdo_time * 1000;
                        if ($index >= $intermediate_count) {
                            $this->log->debug("After $total_count : csv [{$ct} ms.], pdo [{$pt}]");
                            $index = 0;
//                          if ($total_count > 1000) break;
                        }

                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                $start_commit = microtime(true);
                $this->pdo->commit();
                $end_commit = microtime(true);
                $delayInMs  = ($end_commit - $start_commit) * 1000;
                $this->log->debug("Commit took [$delayInMs] ms.");
                fclose($handle);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->pdo->rollBack();
            $this->log->error(prettyStack($e , "While processing [$fn]"));
        }
        $this->log->info(__METHOD__ . " end.");

    }
```

**the puzzle:**

the script takes about 3.5 seconds per 1000 records on pre-prod, dev takes .07 seconds/1000 records on dev.

Following some guidance i found on SO, i added the `beginTransaction` / `commit`.  With that, i get .04 seconds (!!!) /1000 records on pre-prod vs .06 on dev.

**the question**

There must be some obvious mysql setting that explains this rather large difference. I compared both configurations, but cant find anything fundamentally different except 5.7/5.6. Any suggestions in what direction to look?

Comment: It has to be asked if there is a lot of database activity on the pre-production server.

Comment: @mendosi ... nada. This is a box I am grooming from the ground up at the moment. This is the only process running (php cli). From what i can see, when taking forever to execute, both the mysql and the php processes are running at under 3% cpu, suggesting some kind IO waits.

Comment: Sorry for the basic questions, but where is the input file? On which machine is this script being run? Could this be a network bottleneck?

Comment: the file is local to each machine (is being pushed by my CI to each environment).  I did not show this, but the 'rest' of the script takes about 30 ms on both machines (file open, reads, getcsv, etc...). I really isolated this to the "insert" statement.

Answer (score 1):

Do not insert one row at a time; batch them.  That is, have 1000 rows being inserted by each `INSERT` statement.

That will help both servers

To find out why there is a difference, ...  Compare the `CREATE TABLE`.  Compare `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb%';`.  If those don't point out anything, compare all the `VARIABLES`.  The likely suspect is `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`.  Note:  Don't simply look at `my.cnf`; some defaults are different between versions.

Comment: thanks. the `innodb_*` variables are the same. The schema is the same (litteraly the same, both are a git pull outcome, with both git local repos up to date).  Encasing in a beginTransaction/commit is the moral equivalent of batching, and yes, it vastly improves the pre-prod performance. I am still puzzled as to why on my mac i get much better perf than the pre-prod server with one record per commit. I dumped and diffed the variables, and found nothing that could explain this.

Comment: No. `BEGIN; INSERT one row; INSERT one row; ... COMMIT;` is _ten times_ as slow as `BEGIN; INSERT 100 rows; COMMIT;`.  This is largely because of the network and parsing overhead.

Comment: I, too, am puzzled as to why you are seeing a difference.  I was hoping for some subtle setting difference to explain it.

Comment: i will have to study SQL a bit further to figure out the distinction you are making (but i will ;) ).  The only striking diff i see is 5.7 vs 5.6. At this point, this is mostly a knowledge quest : my transactional benchmarks are producing the expected : the faster machine is faster. This is merely a setup  that gets run once in the lifetime of a client config, so anxiety is low.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html -- see "INSERT statements that use VALUES syntax can insert multiple rows...."

Comment: See also `LOAD DATA` syntax for a way to have a csv file with the data.  It is very fast.